# How to mention a paper as a citation which is to be published and not present as a preprint?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science, research-undergraduate, preprint

**Background:**

I have written a paper X. In X, I mention 3 future works which I had thought to take a lot of time to solve. But somehow I managed to finish those early.

Now I want to write a Paper Y on these future works. **But I *want* to submit paper Y before paper X is published.**

**Question:** How can I mention Paper X in Paper Y?

Note: I can not put paper X in a pre-print server because the conference does not allow it.

(Domain: Machine Learning/Computer Science).

Comment: The question is similar but there is no answer on "how to cite" those papers.

Comment: It does! Thank you!